# Extracting several string values by attribute in QGIS graphical model

Tags: qgis, qgis-modeler, expression, extract

I am trying to extract several features by attribute within QGIS 3.12 graphical modeler. The values to extract shall be given by an input and not beeing predefined.

Currently I am using a string-input, but other types would be possible as well (e.g. enum, if that one fits better).

If I would do it manually, it would work like this: `"FieldContainingAttributes" in ('Value1','Value2','Value3')`. But how could this work in graphical modeler?

I've been trying to turn my input string into an array, then the array back into a string with leading and ending singlequotes and separated by comma like this:

```
@fieldcontainingattributes in ('''' || array_to_string(string_to_array(@listcontainingvalues,';'),''',''')  || '''')
```

but without success. Even though the expression `'''' || array_to_string(string_to_array(@listcontainingvalues,';'),''',''')  || ''''` returns `'Value1','Value2',Value3'`. Which should build up the correct expression just like using it manually as above. So it seems like it is not taking this indirect input.

Also `array_contains(string_to_array(@listcontainingvalues,';'),@fieldcontainingattributes)` does not work. But when not using @parameters and instead typing fields or arrays manually, it does.

*After many hours of testing I'm getting the feeling that could be a weird bug due to very strange behavior of the modeler. Sometimes connection lines are not drawn, sometimes they are. Sometimes I am getting the correct output when only typing e.g. `@fieldcontainingattributes` in fieldcalculator, sometimes im just getting no output. Once I even could make a workaround using fieldcalculator inbetween working, but could not reproduce it afterwards... Sidequestion: Can someone confirm such weird things?*

To provide a better context:

[image]

[image]